# Returning an array from a function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I having trouble getting this to work. I just want to return an array from a function, the code i've tried is below.

```
Sub 
   Dim storeData As Variant: Set storeData = getData
   Debug.Print storeData(1)
End Sub

Function getData() As Variant
   Dim arr(2) As Variant
    arr(1) = "ergreg"
    arr(2) = "1005"
    getData = arr
End Function
```

No errors are thrown but nothing is printed to the immediate window

Comment: Remove the `Set`.

Comment: This actually *should* give a type mismatch error.

Comment: @ChrisBull  see answer below (your `Debug.Print storeData(1)` will only print the 2nd of the 3 elements in your array)

Comment: @Comintern I didn't have Option Explicit set, another lesson learnt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake - Thanks @GSerg for finding it.

Just need to remove the 'Set'. So simple

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all the array elements, you need to add a `For` loop to the Debug:

```
Dim storeData As Variant
Dim i As Long
storeData = getData

For i = LBound(storeData) To UBound(storeData)
    Debug.Print storeData(i)
Next i
```

**Quick Note**: `Dim arr(2) As Variant` , means ***arr*** has 3 elements (starting from 0), you are assigning values only to the second and third elements.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have the base set as 1. And i don't need to print all the values, just needed the one for now.